# Точное время timestamp

Tags: node.js, javascript

Как определить точное время на стороне сервера node.js?
и в чем отличие getUTCHours от getHours?

Comment: Взял за основу это: https://npmjs.org/package/time

Comment: > в чем отличие getUTCHours от getHours

первая функция возвращает текущий час по utc, вторая - по локальному.